# Username at LXDE login screen won't remember user

Tags: boot, debian, login, user, lxde

I have Debian with LXDE. After every reboot i have to type username than password. I stumbled to autologin, but i don't want that, instead i want it to remember just username, as most of Desktop environments do. How to fix it to remember the username?

Comment: There is no LXDE login screen. On login screen check which DM (Display Manager) is running. (or better, there is one, but only on Debian Unstable)

Comment: Lightweight desktop environment.

Comment: This is a "Desktop environment". The login is done before loading LXDE, so knowing which X Display Manager are you using, helps on finding how (if it is possible) to change the settings. As I wrote, only very recent LXDE have a own login screen, usually we used other login screens.

Comment: lightdm i guess, how do i find it? by the way fixed my problem

Comment: Try with `update-alternatives --config x-window-manager` in a terminal

Comment: update-alternatives --config x-window-manager shows openbox,  /etc/X11/default-display-manager lightdm

Comment: Sorry. I confused again windows manager with display manager. But you found anyway the default display manager.

Comment: Thank you, your hint helped me. i had no idea about managers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found it. uncommenting "greeter-hide-users =false" at /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf fixes it